# How to import system image into Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've tried to download a system image using Android Studio, but that has always failed. I decided to download the same image (https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/sysimg_x86_64-23_r15.zip) from a browser.

That worked, but now I don't know how to import it into Android Studio. What should I copy where?

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: This was a while ago, but I think I downloaded it through Android Studio after all.